# Passing Values through Query (PHP/MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql

The query below is simply a collection of queries from three different websites linked together to form a single query in a fourth website.

It works fine, but I need to figure out how to maintain each subquery's identity. For example, if the script displays some data from the table calendar_gw, I'd like to know that that data was originally associated with the website GeoWorld (gw). I can then modify the content/display or simply include a note "Data from GeoWorld."

I thought the obvious solution was to simply use an alias, like this...

```
CGZ.Brief AS GZ_Brief
```

I could then go into the while loop and insert something like one of the following...

```
$Brief = $row['GZ_Brief];
$Brief = $row['CGZ.GZ_Brief];
$Brief = $row['CGZ_Brief];
```

But those aren't working for me. Another solution, possibly even better, would be to create a PHP switch that somehow associates a website with the output...

```
switch($Brief)
{
 case 'CGZ_Brief':
 $MySiteID = 'GW';
 break;
 default:
 break;
}
```

Can anyone tell me how to accomplish what I'm trying to do? (By the way, the value $MyURL is simply a page URL, like May_1 in the URL MySite/Calendar/May_1.)

```
$stm = $pdo->prepare("SELECT CGW.N, CGW.URL, CGW.Date, CGW.Year, CGW.Brief
 FROM calendar_gw CGW
 WHERE CGW.URL = :MyURL
 UNION ALL
 SELECT CGZ.N, CGZ.URL, CGZ.Date, CGZ.Year, CGZ.Brief
 FROM calendar_gz CGZ
 WHERE CGZ.URL = :MyURL
 UNION ALL
 SELECT CSL.N, CSL.URL, CSL.Date, CSL.Year, CSL.Brief
 FROM calendar_sl CSL
 WHERE CSL.URL = :MyURL
 ORDER BY Year");
$stm->execute(array(
'MyURL'=>$MyURL
));

$prevYear = null;
while ($row = $stm->fetch())
{
 $Brief2 = $row['Brief'];
   $Year = $row['Year'];
   if ($Year == $prevYear) {
    $YearStr = '&#8226; ';
  } else {
    $YearStr = $Year . '&#8211; ';
    $prevYear = $Year;
 }
  $Brief[] = $YearStr.$row['Brief'];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just add a static value?

```
$stm = $pdo->prepare("SELECT 'CGW' AS Site, CGW.N, CGW.URL, CGW.Date, CGW.Year, CGW.Brief
 FROM calendar_gw CGW
 WHERE CGW.URL = :MyURL
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 'CGZ' AS Site, CGZ.N, CGZ.URL, CGZ.Date, CGZ.Year, CGZ.Brief
 FROM calendar_gz CGZ
 WHERE CGZ.URL = :MyURL
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 'CSL' AS Site, CSL.N, CSL.URL, CSL.Date, CSL.Year, CSL.Brief
 FROM calendar_sl CSL
 WHERE CSL.URL = :MyURL
 ORDER BY Year");
```